# Is this kind of string truncation in c causing memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Will this leak memory?

```
char *str = "Hello/World";
char *pos = rindex(str, '/');
*pos = 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for two reasons: The main reason being that the *contents* of an allocated block don't matter, what matters is freeing any blocks you allocate. The second reason in this *specific* case is that you're writing to a block of memory that wasn't dynamically allocated by the code in the first place (which may result in undefined behavior).

Illustrating the first point, let's actually allocate some memory dynamically:

```
char *str = strdup("Hello/World"); // Allocates a block of memory and copies the string into it
char *pos = rindex(str, '/');      // Finds the slash
*pos = 0;                          // Terminates the string
free(str);                         // Releases the block
```

The fact we wrote a string terminator to the middle of the block is irrelevant, when we free the memory, the entire block is released.

Answer (score 7):

No, but this will invoke undefined behavior as you are writing to a string literal. String literals are not required to be modifiable in C.

Comment: What would be the proper way of doing it?

Comment: @Yvn: `char str[] = "Hello/World";` This allocates an array with contents `Hello/World\0` rather than a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: Use `char str[] = "Hello/World"` instead. It will initialize the `char` array with the elements of the string literal.

Comment: Using `char str[] = "Hello/World";`, the allocation will probably be on the stack, though, which just further complicates things. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, as only dynamic allocated memory can leak (i.e. with malloc et. al.).